# From which font is this math symbol taken?

Tags: fonts, symbols

In a script I came across this direct sum symbol and wondered from which math font it was taken. Moreover, is there a way that I only include this symbol from the respective math font instead of the entire font?
[image]

**Edit:** Running the command yields

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DEHQNH+CMBX12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     273  0
HQYAWK+CMR12                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     274  0
SUHNUL+CMCSC10                       Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     275  0
TMTQDO+CMTT12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     276  0
PEYNJK+CMR9                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     321  0
FZFUMU+TeX-matha12                   Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     361  0
WSQIGY+CMMI12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     362  0
EXAMLM+TeX-mathx10                   Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     367  0
HNDNEG+CMR8                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     368  0
CFDEXU+CMMI8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     369  0
DPBYCI+TeX-matha8                    Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     370  0
MEUJRN+CMTI12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     371  0
PKXVVO+CMMI6                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     377  0
TMHVPV+MSAM10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     378  0
ZUXMJH+CMBX8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     396  0
FTIYQC+CMR6                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     475  0
KNIYEG+TeX-matha6                    Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     674  0
IMFCSC+TeX-mathb12                   Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     753  0
STFEXB+CMEX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     878  0
NDYRHI+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no    1944  0
ZIAHKV+CMBX6                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no    2152  0
```

Comment: Hard to tell ⊕ apart just from an image, if you have that pdf you can see what fonts it uses usng `pdffonts` or your viewer font menu.  `\oplus` is usual latex name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, how do I now extract the correct math font from the table?

Comment: you have the standard cm and ams fonts plus mathabx font matha12 so I guess you want \oplus and mathabx package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot! The second part of my question was about how I can import only the `\oplus` from the `mathabx` package, since I don't want other symbols to change.